Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. Firebase, Flutter
This error started to appear when I tried to do Firebase Authentication (Sign up/ Sign in). Tried different ways still don't know what's the error about. My code would be little messed up after trying different ways to deal with it.
app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.logbook"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.logbook"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 30
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.2.0')
}

project/build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Error Message:


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. A failure occurred while executing
com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction 2
issues were found when checking AAR metadata:


Dependency 'androidx.credentials:credentials:1.2.0-rc01' requires libraries and applications that
depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
Android APIs.
:app is currently compiled against android-33.
Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
plugin 7.3.0 is 33.
Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
compileSdkVerion of at least 34.
Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
on).

Dependency 'androidx.credentials:credentials-play-services-auth:1.2.0-rc01'
requires libraries and applications that
depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
Android APIs.
:app is currently compiled against android-33.
Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
plugin 7.3.0 is 33.
Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
compileSdkVerion of at least 34. Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
on).



Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


BUILD FAILED in 24s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with
exit code 1

